# Was "Narayana" originally a name of Brahma that was transferred to Vishnu in the itihasa-puranas?

Tags: brahma, narayan

This Wiki article says this more than once

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varaha#CITEREFBrockington1998

> The Ayodhya Kanda book of the epic Ramayana refers to Varaha retaining his connection to Prajapati-Brahma. In a cosmogonic myth, Brahma appears in the primal universe full of water and takes the form of a boar to lift the earth from the waters; creation begins with Brahma and his progeny.[16][32][33] The Yuddha Kanda book of the epic praises Rama (the hero of the epic, who is identified with Vishnu) as "the single-tusked boar", which is interpreted as an allusion to Varaha and links Varaha with Vishnu.[34][35][36] In the epic Mahabharata, Narayana ("one who lies in the waters", an appellation of Brahma which was later transferred to Vishnu) is praised as the one who rescues the earth as a boar.[37][38]

> The Puranas complete the full transition of Varaha from the form of Prajapati-Brahma to the avatar of Narayana-Vishnu. The Brahmanda Purana, the Vayu Purana, the Vishnu Purana, the Linga Purana, the Markendeya Purana, the Kurma Purana, the Garuda Purana, the Padma Purana and the Shiva Purana have similar narratives of the cosmogonic myth, wherein Brahma, identified with Narayana-Vishnu, takes the Varaha form to raise the earth from the primeval waters.[39][40][41][42][43][44][45][46][47]

> The Brahmanda Purana, one of the oldest Puranas, narrates that in the present kalpa ("aeon") called Varaha kalpa, Brahma wakes from his slumber. Brahma is called Narayana ("he who lies in the waters").[4

Brahma demurely sitting on a lotus emerging from Vishnu's navel described in almost all puranas and the itihasas also seems to symbolize Brahma's absorption into Vishnu.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the epic Itihāsa, the Mahabharata:

> I am Narayana, the Source of all things, the Eternal, the Unchangeable. I am the Creator of all things, and the Destroyer also of all. I am Vishnu, I am Brahma and I am Shankara, the chief of the gods. I am king Vaisravana, and I am Yama, the lord of the deceased spirits. I am Siva, I am Soma, and I am Kasyapa the lord of the created things. And, O best of regenerate ones, I am he called Dhatri, and he also that is called Vidhatri, and I am Sacrifice embodied. Fire is my mouth, the earth my feet, and the Sun and the Moon are my eyes; the Heaven is the crown of my head, the firmament and the cardinal points are my ears; the waters are born of my sweat. Space with the cardinal points are my body, and the Air is my mind...
> .
> ...And, O Brahmana, whatever is obtained by men by the practice of truth, charity, ascetic austerities, and peace and harmlessness towards all creatures, and such other handsome deeds, is obtained because of my arrangements. Governed by my ordinance, men wander within my body, their senses overwhelmed by me. They move not according to their will but as they are moved by me.

— Mahabharata (translated by Kisari Mohan Ganguli, 1883-1896), Book 3, Varna Parva, Chapter CLXXXVIII (188)[10]

What is Rta ? What is Brahman? What is Narayan? One has to see with the heart as the purpose of all this is not profit and loss, but calmness , satchitananda.

Answer (score -2):

Actually many scriptures calls Lord Brahma as Narayana even by giving the definition of why he is being called so.

Some examples are as follows.:

Lord Brahma as Nārāyaṇa.:

Vishnu Purana.:

> नारायणाख्यो भगवान्ब्रह्मा लोकपितामाहः ॥ १,३.३ ॥उत्पन्नः प्रोच्यते विद्वन्नित्यमेवोपचारतः ॥ १,३.४ ॥
>
> “Hear then how the deity, the beholder of the name Náráyána ,the great parent of the world, Brahmá created all existent things.”

(Said by Rishī Parashara)

Kurma Purana.:

> तदा समभवद्ब्रह्मा सहस्त्राक्षः सहस्त्रपात् ॥ १,६.२ ॥सहस्त्रशीर्षा पुरुषो रुक्मवर्णस्त्वतीन्द्रियः । ब्रह्मा नारायणाख्यस्तु सुष्वाप सलिले तदा ॥ १,६.३ ॥ इमं चोदाहरन्त्यत्र श्लोकं नारायणं प्रति ।
>
> In that vast sheet of water there appeared Brahmā of thousand eyes and thousand feet , the Purusa of thousand heads and of golden colour . He was beyond the scope of sense - organs . Brahmå who was called Nårāyana lay asleep on the cosmic waters at that time . They cite this verse in this context , regarding Narayana , the very embodiment of Brahman ( or the Veda ) and who is the Lord and the origin of the world and the cause of dissolution of the universe !

(Said by Lord Kurma Vishnu)

Manu Smriti 1.9–11 (Not Puranic References, But from Smriti).:

> तदण्डमभवद्धैमं सहस्रांशुसमप्रभम् ।तस्मिञ्जज्ञे स्वयं ब्रह्मा सर्वलोकपितामहः ॥ ॥ आपो नारा इति प्रोक्ता आपो वै नरसूनवः । ता यदस्यायनं पूर्वं तेन नारायणः स्मृतः| यत्तत्कारणमव्यक्तं नित्यं सदसदात्मकम् । तद्विसृष्टः स पुरुषो लोके ब्रह्मेति कीर्त्यते ॥
>
> He became a golden egg (Hiranyagarbha), in brilliancy equal to the sun ; in that ( egg ) he himself was born as Brahma , the progenitor of the whole world_(9).Water is called ' nara , ' — water being the offspring of nara ; since water was created by him (or is recided by that being) , he is , on that account , described as ' nārāyaṇa .'— ( 10 ) That which is the cause—unmanifest, eternal and partaking of the nature of the existent and the non-existent,—the being produced by that (cause) is described among people as ‘brahmā.’—(11)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Emergency burnol first aid kit for victims. Lol. ..